# Query hardware at run-time and dynamically create attributes/properties and setters within `__init__`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function with the following signature:

```
def analog_out(device: str, analog_output: str, voltage: (int, float)):
    # does some hardware manipulation here, this part is working just fine,
    # but i will put a print here just to have something
    print(device, analog_output, voltage)
```

In short, it takes three parameters.

I have the ability to poll the attached hardware at run-time and determine the "names" of the `analog_output`.  For instance, if I poll a particular piece of hardware, I might a list of strings `['ao0', 'ao1']`, each of which would be appropriate to place into the `analog_output` function.

I have a class defined which will provide somewhat convenient access, but I would like to make it more convenient.  At the moment, the convenience class usage looks like:

```
hw = Hardware()
hw.analog_out(analog_output='ai0', voltage=3.3)
```

Again, the above is working just fine, but something is bugging me about the interface.  I would, ideally, like to have something like:

```
hw.ai0 = 3.3
```

I can poll the hardware and set this up in the constructor of the `Hardware` class, but I can't seem to nail the syntax that works.  I'm sure that `__setattr__` is involved, or perhaps `self.__dict__`, but I can't seem to get it going.  For instance, one of my misfires, assuming that I'm trying to write to `ao0`:

```
self.__dict__['ao0'] = lambda v, d=device: analog_out(d, 'ao0', v)
```

which allows me to do something like:

```
hw.ao0(3.3)
```

but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a use case for `__setattr__`.

```
class Hardware:
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self.__dict__[attr] = value


hw = Hardware()
hw.ai0 = 3.3
```

This is probably *too* general, as it allows you to generate outputs on the fly. You can fix that by checking `attr` against an allowed list.

```
class Hardware:
    def __init__(self, allowed_outputs):
        self.outputs = allowed_outputs

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr not in self.outputs:
            raise ValueError(f'Non-existent output {attr}')

        self.__dict__[attr] = value

hw = Hardware(["ao0", "ao1"])
```

Comment: You could add `if hasattr(self, key): settatr(self, key, value)` to protect the attributes of the current object

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It feels correct, but when I run it in python 3.7, it appears that the `__setattr__` is being run before the constructor, so I'm getting an error since `self.outputs` doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Ok, so I moved the `self.outputs` away from the first check in `__setattr__` and that appears to have solved the issue.  I have other class variables that were being set before the `self.outputs`, so those were also interfering.  Thank you, again!